# XeLaTeX: How to put a table above the title in \documentclass{article}

Tags: tables, xetex

I am looking to put a table in the top of the title page.
Reason: The document (an SOP) requires that all revisions are listed at the top of the title, on the first page.
I can't figure out how to do this...image below shows what I can do using
the following code:

```
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{center}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{|l|C{0.5}|R{1.5}|}
    \hline
    \it{Approved Revision}      & \it Revision Date &  \it Details\\
       \hline
    \small Rev01-Apr0419-JL     &   April 4 -2019   &  First document\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center} 
......
\end{document}
```

[image: Title over table] 
I need to have the table **above** the title... any suggestions? Thanks -

Comment: Could you please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass and the relevant packages? Apart from that you might be interested in the `titlepage` environment or the `titling` package.

Comment: I believe that `article`, like `amsart`, explicitly prohibits putting floats at the top of the first page.  However, `amsart` has the facility for inserting a journal logo in the upper left-hand corner, and that mechanism might be used to sneak in your table of revisions.  I don't currently have local access to tex, so can't provide the detailed code, but that's where I'd adapt it from.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nonstandard page style for the first page. Adjust the amount of raising to your liking.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@first{%
  \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
  \def\@oddhead{\revision@table}%
  \let\@evenhead\@oddhead
  \def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\hfil\thepage\hfil}%
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
}
\def\revision@table{\raisebox{0.5in}[0pt][0pt]{%
  \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}[b]{|l|c|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|}
  \hline
  \itshape Approved Revision & \itshape Revision Date & \itshape Details\\
  \hline
  \joel@revision & \joel@revdate & \joel@revnote \\
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}%
}}
\def\revision#1{\def\joel@revision{#1}}
\def\revisiondate#1{\def\joel@revdate{#1}}
\def\revisionnote#1{\def\joel@revnote{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\revision{Rev01-Apr0419-JL}
\revisiondate{April 4, 2019}
\revisionnote{First document}

\title{Standard Operating Procedure \\ for LISAR Instrument}
\author{Rev01-Apr0419-JL}
\date{}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{first}

\end{document}
```

[image]